# I want sqlite software to install in ubuntu..where can i get that?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working eclipse to develop android apps in ubuntu OS.I am getting sqlite for windows..Does it work same in ubuntu or is there any sqlite for ubuntu only? please help me..I have to download sqlite now for ubnutu.so help me which should i download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. From the "Admin" menu, select the "Synaptic Package Manager"
2. In the package manager's search box, type "sqlite" and click on search
3. Select the sqlite package you want, and click install

Sqlite is available for a very large number of platforms, including Linux (i.e. including Ubuntu). The install package is different for each platform, but the sqlite calls from your program should work the same. For more information, you can always see the [sqlite home page](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you ran into [this problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312424). Check out the comments for possible solutions.